# What are the Maven dependencies to use hibernate, hibernate annotations, and ehcache?

Tags: hibernate, dependencies, maven, ehcache

I would like to update my Maven pom.xml with the latest hibernate, hibernate-annotations, and ehcache dependencies.

I read the hibernate download page and the ehcache donwload page. All my tries at interpreting it seem to fail. Can someone write out the snippet that should go into pom.xml?

Cryptic hibernate download page:
http://hibernate.org/downloads

Cryptic ehcache download page:
http://www.terracotta.org/dl/ehcache-oss-download-catalog

Here is what I have so far:

```
   <properties>
       <hibernate.version>3.6.0.Final</hibernate.version>
   </properties>
   <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
                <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
                <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
                <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
 </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>codehaus-repository</id>
            <name>Codehaus</name>
            <url>https://nexus.codehaus.org/content/repositories/releases/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>java.net</id>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/1</url>
            <layout>legacy</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Maven Repository Switchboard</name>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>sonatype-ehcache</id>
            <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/sourceforge-releases</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>JBoss Repository</id>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

I know, it looks like a big mess, because I don't seem to figure out, where all the dependencies are stored.

The above fails with:

```
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
```

Update:
Pascal, your reply is very clear and well explained. However, hibernate still fails on startup.

1. sl4j threw errors, which went away by adding:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
       <version>1.6.1</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. There are many instances of this warning:

   ```
   g in the two-phase commit!
   1797 [main] WARN  net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory  - No Tr
   ansactionManagerLookup found in Hibernate config, XA Caches will be participatin
   ```
3. Additionally, this error makes everything fail:

   Related cause:

   ```
   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean wit
   h name 'financialDAO' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/applic
   ationContext-database.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'transactionManager
   ' while setting bean property 'transactionManager'; nested exception is org.spri
   ngframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '
   transactionManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/applicat
   ionContext-database.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' whil
   e setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframewor
   k.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFac
   tory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/applicationContext-dat
   abase.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.Null
   PointerException
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver
   .resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
   ```

To confirm, this is the spring configuration:

```
<!-- Enable EHCache -->
<prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
<prop key="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">/ehcache.xml</prop>
```

Update:
This seems to be the latest exception that hibernate gets stuck on:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.HibernateUtil.loadAndCorrectConfiguration(HibernateUtil.java:48)
    at net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory.start(EhCacheRegionFactory.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1842)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:855)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:774)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1469)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1409)
```

Comment: Try without your ehcache.xml for now (i.e. remove it from your spring configuration).

Comment: When I remove all ehcache entries in hibernateproperties, the app starts fine. When I remove only the configurationResourceName entry, it says that it is using the failover configuration.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you really mean the ultimate versions of hibernate-annotations (and not hibernate-entitymanager) and ehcache, then you'll need the following:

```
<project>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>3.6.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
       <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
       <version>2.2.0</version>
   </dependency>
   ...
  </dependencies>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>repository.jboss.org-public</id>
      <name>JBoss repository</name>
      <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  ...
</project>
```

As of Hibernate 3.6, JDK 1.4 support has been dropped and the Hibernate Annotations have been merged back into Core.

I you meant Hibernate EntityManager, then replace `hibernate-core` by `hibernate-entitymanager` in the above snippet.

Regarding EHCache, `ehcache-core` should provide everything you need (including implementations of the "new" [Hibernate 3.3/3.5 caching SPI](http://relation.to/Bloggers/Ehcache20SupportsNewHibernate33CachingProvider) with its `CacheRegionFactory`). So, as [documented](http://ehcache.org/documentation/hibernate.html#Setting_Ehcache_as_the_Hibernate_Second_Level_Cache):

> ### [Setting Ehcache as the Hibernate Second Level Cache](http://ehcache.org/documentation/hibernate.html#Setting_Ehcache_as_the_Hibernate_Second_Level_Cache)
>
> #### Hibernate 3.3 and higher
>
> **ATTENTION HIBERNATE 3.2 USERS**
>
> **Make sure to note the change to BOTH the property name and value.**
>
> Use:
>
> ```
> <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">
>           net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory</property>
> ```
>
> for instance creation, or
>
> ```
> <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">
>           net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory</property>
> ```
>
> to force Hibernate to use a singleton
>   of Ehcache CacheManager.

---

**Follow-up:** To answer your update:

> sl4j threw errors, which went away by adding (...)

Well, I can't guess what logging framework you're using, providing the binding of your choice was left as an exercise for the reader :)

> There are many instances of this warning (...)

I get only one **`WARNING`** when running in a non JTA environment. If that's your case (a non JTA environment), I would consider the `WARNING` as normal. If that's not your case, have a look at the documentation about [JTA](http://ehcache.org/documentation/jta.html).

> Additionally, this error makes everything fail

This is somehow a different question (but it looks like the `SessionFactory` fails to initialize properly, activate logging to see why) and I suggest to post a new spring specific question.

Comment: formatting in the comment box is horrible, will update the question above.

Comment: Pascal, again thanks a lot for your help. You seem very sharp. And, it probably makes sense to start a new question for the configuration issue.

Answer (score 4):

You can go by this pom.xml if you are integrating Spring 3 with hibernate 3

```
<properties>
    <org.springframework.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Core utilities used by other modules. Define this if you use Spring 
        Utility APIs (org.springframework.core.*/org.springframework.util.*) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Expression Language (depends on spring-core) Define this if you use 
        Spring Expression APIs (org.springframework.expression.*) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Bean Factory and JavaBeans utilities (depends on spring-core) Define 
        this if you use Spring Bean APIs (org.springframework.beans.*) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP) Framework (depends on spring-core, 
        spring-beans) Define this if you use Spring AOP APIs (org.springframework.aop.*) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Application Context (depends on spring-core, spring-expression, spring-aop, 
        spring-beans) This is the central artifact for Spring's Dependency Injection 
        Container and is generally always defined -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Various Application Context utilities, including EhCache, JavaMail, 
        Quartz, and Freemarker integration Define this if you need any of these integrations -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Transaction Management Abstraction (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, 
        spring-aop, spring-context) Define this if you use Spring Transactions or 
        DAO Exception Hierarchy (org.springframework.transaction.*/org.springframework.dao.*) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JDBC Data Access Library (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, 
        spring-tx) Define this if you use Spring's JdbcTemplate API (org.springframework.jdbc.*) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Object-to-Relation-Mapping (ORM) integration with Hibernate, JPA, 
        and iBatis. (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, spring-tx) 
        Define this if you need ORM (org.springframework.orm.*) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Object-to-XML Mapping (OXM) abstraction and integration with JAXB, 
        JiBX, Castor, XStream, and XML Beans. (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, 
        spring-context) Define this if you need OXM (org.springframework.oxm.*) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Web application development utilities applicable to both Servlet and 
        Portlet Environments (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context) 
        Define this if you use Spring MVC, or wish to use Struts, JSF, or another 
        web framework with Spring (org.springframework.web.*) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring MVC for Servlet Environments (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, 
        spring-context, spring-web) Define this if you use Spring MVC with a Servlet 
        Container such as Apache Tomcat (org.springframework.web.servlet.*) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring MVC for Portlet Environments (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, 
        spring-context, spring-web) Define this if you use Spring MVC with a Portlet 
        Container (org.springframework.web.portlet.*) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Support for testing Spring applications with tools such as JUnit and 
        TestNG This artifact is generally always defined with a 'test' scope for 
        the integration testing framework and unit testing stubs -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Hibernate resources -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0.ga</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- EhCache -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Taglibs -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>20030825.184428</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
        <version>20030825.183949</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Log4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.14</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And if you want different versions of hibernate you can check [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
  <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".