# Mavem Hibernate dependency - which one to choose?

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

I want to set up hibernate using Maven. In the pom.xml, I have an option to add a dependency.

When I go there and I want to add a dependency to hibernate, I type "hibernate" in the search bar.

I get a big list of results and I don't know which I should choose.

How do I figure out what do I need for a simple application which uses hibernate?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the Maven dependencies to use hibernate, hibernate annotations, and ehcache?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092558/what-are-the-maven-dependencies-to-use-hibernate-hibernate-annotations-and-ehc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are starting a new project then most likely you want to use annotation-based configuration, then you need next libraries:

- [hibernate-core](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core) - main library
- [hibernate-annotations](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-annotations) - annotations to avoid huge xml configurations.
- [hibernate-entitymanager](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager) - to use [EntityManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html)

And optionally some of these:

- [hibernate-c3p0](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-c3p0) - for connection pooling with [c3p0](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/)
- [hibernate-ehcache](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-ehcache) - for caching

Comment: hibernate-annotations are not necessary anymore, see the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092558/what-are-the-maven-dependencies-to-use-hibernate-hibernate-annotations-and-ehc)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any specific advice regarding Hibernate dependencies, but I would suggest you look for a tutorial regarding Hibernate and whatever specific use case or problem you are trying to solve. Then, determine which dependencies *you* need